# versionNameSuffix does not work in Android studio 4.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

As you know, gradle stopped ([official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#version_properties_removed_from_buildconfig_class_in_library_projects)) support VERSION_CODE and VERSION_NAME in the Gradle DSL. For more info click [hire](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/10/14/android-studio-4p1-library-modules-version-code.html). So, I added this code (app build.gradle):

```
        defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0" 
        buildConfigField 'int', 'VERSION_CODE', "1"           //fix issue
        buildConfigField 'String', 'VERSION_NAME', "\"1.0\"" //fix issue
        }
//..
        buildTypes {
             debugToast{
               versionNameSuffix "-debug(Toasts)" //NOW DOES NOT WORK !!
             }
        }
//..
```

And my question: How fix *versionNameSuffix* method, because it doesn't work?